# Add textbox to grid with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, grid

I am fairly new to C#.  I am trying to add a textbox to the grid by clicking a button.  When I click this button, everything on my grid disappears:

```
    private void addLine_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
        txt.Name = "textBox8";
        dxfLines.Children.Add(txt);
    }
```

Here is the xaml too:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DXFGenerator" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid Name="dxfLines">
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="271,94,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <Button Content="Generate DXF" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="286,194,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="84" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Button Content="Add Line" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="391,196,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="addLine_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It just lay over the content since you haven't specified row and column to place so by default it will take 0th row and 0th column. Either set them or use StackPanel.

Comment: It would be helpful if could post your Xaml code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a grid you need to define rows and columns. Your xaml should look something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DXFGenerator" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid Name="dxfLines" x:FieldModifier="private" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" />
        <Button Content="Generate DXF" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="84" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Button Content="Add Line" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="addLine_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You also need to specify a row and column for the text box you are adding so the grid knows where to place the text box. The content of your addLine click should look something like:

```
System.Windows.Controls.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
txt.Name = "textBox8";
Grid.SetColumn(txt,1);
Grid.SetRow(txt, 1);
dxfLines.Children.Add(txt);
```

Besides, keep in mind that, in order to add a new child item, you select the Grid form and not the Window form . The Window form does not have the *Children* property, however in this example the *Grid* form has it.